# How can I fix ERR_TTY_INIT_FAILED when initializing TTY in a Node.js Git Bash environment?

Tags: node.js, git-bash

## [ERR_TTY_INIT_FAILED]: TTY initialization failed: uv_tty_init returned EBADF (bad file descriptor)

```
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

SystemError [ERR_TTY_INIT_FAILED]: TTY initialization failed: uv_tty_init returned EBADF (bad file descriptor)
    at new SystemError (node:internal/errors:250:5)
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:361:7)
    at new WriteStream (node:tty:93:11)
    at oD.prompt (file:///D:/Shirish/github/vitepress-documentation/node_modules/vitepress/dist/node/serve-d5608de4.js:56564:714)
    at J (file:///D:/Shirish/github/vitepress-documentation/node_modules/vitepress/dist/node/serve-d5608de4.js:56579:7)
    at root (file:///D:/Shirish/github/vitepress-documentation/node_modules/vitepress/dist/node/serve-d5608de4.js:58671:19)
    at $e (file:///D:/Shirish/github/vitepress-documentation/node_modules/vitepress/dist/node/serve-d5608de4.js:56596:95)
    at init (file:///D:/Shirish/github/vitepress-documentation/node_modules/vitepress/dist/node/serve-d5608de4.js:58669:25)
    at file:///D:/Shirish/github/vitepress-documentation/node_modules/vitepress/dist/node/cli.js:420:5
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25) {
  code: 'ERR_TTY_INIT_FAILED',
  info: {
    errno: -4083,
    code: 'EBADF',
    message: 'bad file descriptor',
    syscall: 'uv_tty_init'
  },
  errno: [Getter/Setter],
  syscall: [Getter/Setter]
}
```

I've tried initiating node app, `npx vitepress init`